# Memcached set_many and get_many failing when trying more than 100 k,v pairs in django..why?

Tags: django, memcached

I'm have a dictionary of data that I would like to cache, so I use:

```
cache.set_many(dict_to_cache, TTL)
```

for a dictionary that has more than 100 entries, it does not seem to set. No error is thrown, and it doesn't seem that anything is getting evicted, it just doesn't save. My work around was to simply break up the dictionary into 100 key chunks via a method:

```
def dict_chunker(data, SIZE=100):
    it = iter(data)
    for i in xrange(0, len(data), SIZE):
        yield {k:data[k] for k in islice(it, SIZE)}
```

That seems to work fine, but I am wondering what would make it not set for dictionaries over 100 entries?

I had the same issue with getting more than 100 keys at a time.

```
dict = cache.get_many(list_of_keys)
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Is it a particularly massive dictionary? There is a 1Mb limit on objects http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/ha-memcached-faq.html#qandaitem-17-6-5-1-2

Comment: Thanks for response! And no... but even if it was, shouldn't it have some sort of error? My first inclination was that it was indeed, the size, but I believe the "objects" are each individual entry... not the dictionary as a whole. My entries are far below 1Mb.